# How do I switch from a UIView to a UITable View?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview

I am writing an app that does not utilize a navigationController - there is only one area that requires a UITable.

However, now I am hitting a roadblock when I go to load in that (table) view, with a method such as:

```
searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] 
                            initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:searchViewController.view];
```

Do I need to load the method (below) into my AppDelegate?

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

And then, once I do that, can I call that TableView in the same way? Or do I need to use another method, such as the one below:

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add a navigation controller to your project, add it to your app delegate header file.

```
UINavigationController  *navigationController;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Then in your implemplentation file you would add:

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

the "view" is being called from the MainWindow.xib file so you will need to add a navigation controller object to that nib and hook it up to the view you are wanting to fist load.

Of course don't forget to use

```
@synthesize navigationController;
```

and release it when dealloc is called.

```
[navigationController release];
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't have a MainWindow.xib file when I created my project...Is this a problem? Do I need one?

I created the project from scratch, not specifying a Navigation-based project...

Comment: Also, I have been using 'self.view addSubview' instead of 'window addSubview'...is this a problem if I want to begin adding 'window addSubview'?